# Greatest Common Divisor - Upper bound

Tags: algorithm

I'm curious about the GCD problem. I am taking the Coursera Algorithmic toolbox course, and it states that the naive solution to the problem is:

```
for d from 1 to a+b:
    if d|a and d|b:
        best(or max) d
return best
```

I'm confused by this though. Wouldn't the maximum possible divisor be min(a,b) instead of a+b? since the smaller of the two couldn't possibly be divided by the larger of the two?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. You could rewrite the algorithm, that the loop stop by min(a,b)

```
for d from 1 to min(a,b):
    if d|a and d|b:
        best(or max) d
return best
```

This implementation is faster than the first one. You could still improve it by looping backward:

```
for d from min(a,b) to 1:
    if d|a and d|b:
       break
return d
```